# Is this a bug in the compiler or Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, generics, clr

The following code produces a failed build with 0 (zero) errors, warnings, or even messages.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Ghost_Error
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CrazyMethods<ISomeInterface> cm = new CrazyMethods<ISomeInterface>();
            cm.Crazy(gm => gm.DoSomething</*anything goes here*/>());
        }
    }

    class CrazyMethods<T>
    {
        public void Crazy<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression) { }
    }

    interface ISomeInterface { }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static int DoSomething<T>(this ISomeInterface gm)
        {
            return default(int);
        }
    }
}
```

Only if you change the build output to Detailed, can you find the following error `error CS7003: Unexpected use of an unbound generic name`. It will however never appear in the Error List and you'll never see it in the output unless you change the build output verbosity. Attempting to execute the code will result in a build failure message with no additional details.

Should this be reported? Is it reported? Where should it be reported?

Edit: This is confirmed with another developers machine: if the drop down in the Error List is set to "Build + IntelliSense", the Error disappears.

Comment: What level do you normally have it set at?

Comment: the default of "Normal"

Comment: Where are you setting that?

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity

Comment: Mine is set to minimal and I see the error.

Comment: OK, crazy. In the Error List window, I had the drop down set to "Build + IntelliSense". If I change it to "Build Only", the error appears. However, it still does not highlight the error inside the editor.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? I don't have that option, only Build and IntelliSense as distinct items.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio go to "Help" | "Send Feedback" | "Report a Problem...". Describe the problem as best as you can to determine if the problem has already been reported. When I entered "CS7003" it says "Be the first to send us a report about this problem" so assuming it is a problem it seems it has not yet been reported. Click the "Create New Issue" button.